# In Java why this error: 'attribute value must be constant'?

Tags: java, annotations, testng, constants

I have some TestNG code, where I am passing a Test annotation parameter called `timeOut = TESTNG_TEST_TIMEOUT` .

```
@Test(description = "Tests something.", groups = { "regression" }, 
   timeOut = TESTNG_TEST_TIMEOUT, enabled = true)
```

And in my TestBase class I have this member:

```
public final static long TESTNG_TEST_TIMEOUT = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5);
```

When I use the above line of code, I get a 'attribute value must be constant' error in Eclipse.

But, if I simply define the member like so, it works:

```
public final static long TESTNG_TEST_TIMEOUT = 300000;
```

Is the use of TimeUnit not a constant?

Comment: @HotLicks tried using static init block and it didn't work for me unfortunately

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This

```
public final static long TESTNG_TEST_TIMEOUT = 300000;
```

is a [constant variable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4), a type of [constant expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).

This

```
public final static long TESTNG_TEST_TIMEOUT = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5);
```

is not.

Annotation members [expect](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.1) constant expressions (and a few other things like enums and `Class` literals).

Comment: Thanks for the hyperlinks.  I can see that the doc says a constant must be a primitive or a predeclared String.   Thanks.

Comment: I'd also add that public final static long TESTNG_TEST_TIMEOUT = 50; is a constant variable, but public final static long TESTNG_TEST_TIMEOUT = 50 + 60; is not.

Comment: @java Actually, it is.

Comment: Just an fyi for others, `public static final Long TESTING_TEST_TIMEOUT = 300000L;` is also not a constant value, use the primitive `long` instead