# Attribute value must be constant error using Contentful Space

Tags: java, contentful

Am getting the error message:

> Attribute value must be constant

while defining a Space annotation for my Space class:

[image]

I've looked at the question [In Java why this error: 'attribute value must be constant'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28031784/in-java-why-this-error-attribute-value-must-be-constant) which is the closest to my problem but it doesn't help.

Am using the latest `Vault` library:

```
compile 'com.contentful.vault:core:2.1.0'
```

The previous version didn't require a `Locale` attribute.
How do I solve this?

Comment: It would have been easier to help you if you'd provided your code as *text* and then the error message as text beneath it. That would have given us just as much information, but then I wouldn't be having to type out the declaration again manually in an answer...

Comment: My bad, I just wanted to show it as is

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the [Javadoc for `Space`](https://contentful.github.io/vault/com/contentful/vault/Space.html) you'll see that the `locales` attribute is a `String[]` - so just provide the IDs of the locals:

```
@Space(value = "id",
       dbVersion = 1,
       models = NewsVault.class,
       locales = { "en" })
```

Comment: Sigh...That did it

Answer (score 3):

Mario, Java Ecosystem Developer at Contentful, here. The easiest would be to declare `Locale.ENGLISH` like so:

`public static final String ENGLISH = "en-US";`

Or whatever your default locale is. Alternatively you could just use the string from above instead of the constant.

Greetings,
Mario