# Class final variable is not final

Tags: java

Why isn't this variable considered to be final? This code does not compile, I would say it is a bug or at least is strange..

```
public class QualifierConfiguration {
    public static final String RANK_CALCULATOR = RankCalculatorImpl.class.getName();
}


public class Implementation{
    private final RankCalculator rankCalculator;
    public Implementation(@Qualifier(QualifierConfiguration.RANK_CALCULATOR) RankCalculator rankCalculator){
        this.rankCalculator = rankCalculator;
    }
}
```

and not even this does not work

```
public class QualifierConfiguration {
    public static final String RANK_CALCULATOR = getValue();
    private static String getValue(){
        return "string";
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you pursue this further?

Answer (score 1):

A `final` variable is not necessarily a compile-time constant:

[4.12.4. final Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)

> A variable can be declared final. A final variable may only be assigned to once.
> …
> A *constant variable* is a final variable of primitive type or type `String` that is initialized with a constant expression ([§15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)).

`RankCalculatorImpl.class.getName()` is not a constant expression, neither is `getValue()`.

Note that for annotation having a `Class` value, class literals like `RankCalculatorImpl.class` are allowed, due to the specific rules for annotations, but they still don’t make compile-time constants (the same applies to `enum` constant references). For primitive and `String` values, [the specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.1-300) clearly mandates constant expressions for the annotation values:

> An element type `T` is commensurate with an element value `V` if and only if one of the following is true:
> …
>
> - `T` is not an array type, and the type of `V` is assignment compatible (§5.2) with T, and:
>
>   - If `T` is a primitive type or `String`, then `V` is a constant expression (§15.28).
>   - If `T` is `Class` or an invocation of `Class` (§4.5), then `V` is a class literal (§15.8.2).
>   - If `T` is an enum type (§8.9), then `V` is an enum constant (§8.9.1).
>   - `V` is not `null`.

So here, you have no other choice than specifying the actual qualified name as string literal:

```
public static final String RANK_CALCULATOR = "actual.package.name.RankCalculatorImpl";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a constant expression to an annotation. So it has to be constant during compile time. You can get more info about compile time constants [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28). Similar SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28031784/in-java-why-this-error-attribute-value-must-be-constant).

The exception you get from this is: `The value for annotation attribute Qualifier.value must be a constant expression`